# Can the core Java HttpClient proxy through a TLS Proxy?

Tags: java, https, proxy, java-http-client

I am trying to setup a HttpClient to proxy requests through a HTTPS authenticated proxy.

It seems the Java HttpClient can only proxy over `http` and therefore the proxy credentials are sent in plaintext to the proxy.

I have opened the proxy on port 8443 to accept `http` and this works fine:

```java
System.setProperty("jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes", "");
String user = "username";
String password = "password";

Authenticator authenticator = new ProxyAuthenticator(user, password);
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
    .sslContext(getSSLContextTrustAny())
    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
    .proxy(ProxySelector.of(new InetSocketAddress("my.proxy", 8443)))
    .authenticator(Authenticator.getDefault())
    .build();

String uri = "https://ensc1aqsjv0asda.x.pipedream.net/";
String msg = "test-msg";

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create(uri))
    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(msg))
    .build();

HttpResponse<?> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());

System.out.println(response);
System.out.println(response.headers());
```

(Note: `getSSLContextTrustAny()` returns an SSLContext that trusts any cert as the proxy is using a self signed CA)

However, when I set the port to 443 (which is open), the request just times out. I suspect the client is trying to proxy to `http://my.proxy:443` instead of over TLS to  `https://my.proxy:443`

Is it possible to make the client use `https` for proxying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - this is not supported. It is possible to tunnel an HTTPS connection to a server through a clear connection to a proxy, but it is not possible to proxy a clear HTTP connection to a server through an encrypted connection to a proxy.

Comment: Thanks @daniel , is this just a limitation of the HttpClient or Java in general? If I move to the Apache client or the old`UrlConnection`, will it be possible?

Comment: I believe the legacy stack (`URL.openConnection()`, `java.net.HttpURLConnection` `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`) behave the same. I don't know for other clients.